# how to get driver for epson l360

Tags: drivers

Is there a website or someplace I can go to get the correct drivers and software for Epson L360 inkjet printer. I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you even try to Google? Googling "Epson L360 Linux Drives", the first link is http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supAdvice.jsp?noteoid=162111&type=highlights This leads you to http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX Here, you can type your model number and you get to download the proprietary drivers.  The **second** link of the Google search, links you to the "OpenPrinting" website, which is a reference for Linux Printing.  http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-L360_Series  The printer is supported "Perfectly".  Linux most likely had built-in drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this link: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule and type **L360**. Make sure you select **Linux** from the operating system drop-down list.